# Conditional Convolution

Tags: conditional, convolution

I was hoping to incorporate an `If` function into a `Convolve` operation, as in

```
Convolve[
 (-E^(-2 x) + E^-x) (7 - 3 If[-E^(-2 x) + E^-x >= 0, 1, 0]) +
 (-E^(-2 x) + 2 E^-x) (2 - 2 If[-E^(-2 x) + 2 E^-x >= 0, 1, 0]) +
 (E^(-2 x)/4 - 2 E^-x + 1/4 (7 - 6 x + 2 x^2)) *
 (3 - 2 If[E^(-2 x)/4 - 2 E^-x + 1/4 (7 - 6 x + 2 x^2) >= 0, 1, 0]) +
 (150 - 100 If[(2 E^(-2 x))/5 - E^-x/2 + 1/100 (10 Cos[x] + 30 Sin[x]) >=0, 1, 0]) *
 ((2 E^(-2 x))/5 - E^-x/2 + 1/100 (10 Cos[x] + 30 Sin[x]))[x],
 Sqrt[1/2 Pi]*Exp[-x^2/2] - 1,
 x, y
]
```

But at each time I run the programme computer does not respond. Can you tell me if the code is correct?

I see I will try Heaviside theta function.

---

I mean after executing the code I waited for about 5 hours without interrupting mathematica but it did not give me any input. There was still 'Running' on the window.

Comment: `If` is not a mathematical function. Try something like `HeavisideTheta` instead. Also, what do you mean "the computer does not respond"? Do you mean that *Mathematica* crashes? (Also, please note how I formatted your post. Please don't use $\TeX$ markup in place of code blocks.)

Comment: Also, your function `f` (the first one inside `Convolve`) is not defined correctly. You have a trailing `[x]`, but the head is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computation (even after fixing the superfluous `[x]` and introducing `HeavisideTheta`) involves amounts of memory I'd call "extreme": After 20mins, it is well beyond 11 GB, and 20 mins later the kernel crashes (in a way, see below) due to all my 32 GB of RAM (and all of pagefile space) having been consumed.

> Sidenote: In the given case, *Mathematica*'s behavior is identical for `If`, `HeavisideTheta` and `UnitStep`.

Therefore, my (sorry for the bad news!) answer is:

**You cannot hope to get a result on a typical PC nowadays.**

---

This is the code I actually used (you may also use your `If`-version, or `UnitStep`, since it makes no difference in the outcome):

```
f = (-E^(-2 x) + E^-x) (7 - 
     3 HeavisideTheta[-E^(-2 x) + E^-x]) + (-E^(-2 x) + 2 E^-x) (2 - 
     2 HeavisideTheta[-E^(-2 x) + 2 E^-x]) + (E^(-2 x)/4 - 2 E^-x + 
     1/4 (7 - 6 x + 2 x^2))*(3 - 
     2 HeavisideTheta[
       E^(-2 x)/4 - 2 E^-x + 1/4 (7 - 6 x + 2 x^2)]) + (150 - 
     100 HeavisideTheta[(2 E^(-2 x))/5 - E^-x/2 + 
        1/100 (10 Cos[x] + 30 Sin[x])])*((2 E^(-2 x))/5 - E^-x/2 + 
     1/100 (10 Cos[x] + 30 Sin[x]));

g = Sqrt[1/2 Pi]*Exp[-x^2/2] - 1;

{f, g} = FullSimplify /@ {f, g};

Convolve[f, g, x, y]
```

---

Interesting to note, though, that the kernel did *not* crash entirely, but just stopped its activities, obviously due to running out of available memory, but *did not* produce either

- a result or at least
- an error message

Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using `UnitStep` to create a conditional function

```
h = Exp[-x] UnitStep[x] + (1 - UnitStep[x]) Exp[-2 x];
f = Exp[-2 x];
Convolve[f, h, x, y]

-E^(-2 y) - E^(-2 y) y
```